# User Defined Function to Sum by FontStyle Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a user-defined code that automatically sums any number in a referenced font.

I've used a very similar code multiple times for interior color that worked without a hitch. I've tried font.name and font.fontstyle, is this even possible? If so, what's breaking this function?

```
Function SumCellsbyFont(rData As Range, cellRefFont As Range)
    Dim indRefFont As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim sumRes

    Application.Volatile
    sumRes = 0
    indRefFont = cellRefFont.Cells(1, 1).Font.FontStyle
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefFont = cellCurrent.Font.FontStyle Then
            sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    SumCellsbyFont = sumRes

End Function
```

I expected it to reference the cell that I designate and look for numbers with the same font style one at a time. If it has the same font style I want it to add it to the variable `sumRes` until it has gone through all the cells in the designated range. The only output it gives me is #value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`FontStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.fontstyle) is a `String`, not a `Long`.

Change `Dim indRefFont As Long` to `Dim indRefFont As String`.

[image]

Though to be honest, I don't think `Application.Volatile` will work here - the UDF will not be recalculated when you change the font of the cell(s). That might be a design flaw in this approach.

Comment: @StevenL. thanks. Note the last sentence... up to you, but just an FYI on a potential issue. You may have to recalc manually. You might as well get rid of `Application.Volatile`.